# How to mount image.ext2 file system that is in iso9660 image (livecd)

Tags: filesystems, mount, livecd

I have ISO9660 image. In this image there are isolinux bootloader, small initrd.gz filesystem, Linux kernel and real root.ext2/3/4 file system. After in virtual machine the system was loaded in the system this ISO image exists as a /dev/sr0 device. As all knows the /dev/sr0 device can be mount into a directory /mnt. After this action the content of the mounted device looks something like this:

`mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
ls /mnt
/isolinux root.ext2`

Question is: how to mount the root.ext2 file system, that is in /dev/sr0 device, as a general file system (/)?

I tried to mount /mnt/root.ext2 image to /new-directory and after to use pivot_root or switch_root, but this dosen't work.

`mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
mount /mnt: WARNING: source write-protected, mounted read only.
mkdir /new-root
cd /mnt
mount root.ext2 /new-root
umount -l /mnt
cd /
exec switch_root /new-root /sbin/init`

and then system hangs:

`Usage: init {-e VAR[=VAL] | [-t SECONDS] {0|1|2|3|4|5|6|s|Q|Q|A|a|B|b|C|C|U|u}}`

Thank you.

Comment: You can loop mount: `sudo mount -o loop /mnt/root.ext2 /new-root`. I think you should keep `/mnt` mounted (don't unmount it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sododus. I tried with the option you offered, but the result is the same.

Comment: Normally, with modern Linux distros, you need not tamper with mounting, if you clone the iso file to a device like a USB drive. Then boot into that device and you should have the content of the iso file active and/or available. -- It will probably be easier to help, if you tell us as much as possible about the iso file and how you want to use it.

Comment: sudodus, I develope minimal Linux system from scratch and I'm ashamed to show it, because it has a lot of lame solutions. I hoped a quick solution on this issue, but now I think I would better will learn on my own. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you again.

Comment: I see and I think you are right. One way to take steps forward is to look at tools for this purpose, for example [Cubic](https://ubunlog.com/en/ubuntu-custom-cubic-iso/) and how it works, or go really basic with [Linux From Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) (LFS). Good luck, and feel welcome to ask here (and other forums and mailing lists). There is a lot of help available :-)